# svg background to cover the whole page

Tags: css, svg, background-image

how could a SVG image cover an entire HTML page in a way that I can vertically scroll through it while it has 100% width? I tried the following but I can not scroll through it even if i declare overflow: scroll on the body tag.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">
          * {
            background: url(home.svg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: scroll;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Making it a background image means it won't make its container stretch (so `overflow: scroll;` won't do anything) - have you tried using an `<img>` tag instead (and give that `width: 100%;`)?

Comment: @xec thank you! I couldn't believe it was that simple.